# Custom authorization inside WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, iauthorizationfilter

I would like to know how can I change the order or `do something` to control the execution order of methods.

**`I have this class prototype:`**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public abstract class ApiDbAuthAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter {
     public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
         // this I want to go off first
     }

     public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        // this I want to go off after the first
     }

     public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) {
        // this at the end
     }
}
```

**What actually is going on:**

```
 1. OnAuthorization
 2. OnActionExecuting
 3. OnActionExecuted
```

I know that, this is the correct order and I know it's should be that way,
But I'm triggering **`UnitOfWork OnActionExecuting`**,
the reason why I'm using DB when I'm using this filter.
PS: I'm using

```
using IAuthorizationFilter = System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter;
```

I know there a difference between **`System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthorizationFilter`**,
But I haven't found the to implement this and I don't know if I needed to do it at all.

How can I change the order or how can I solve that ?

Comment: i think you should rephrase some sentences. I am not able to understand your issue. what methods you want to change order for and why is not clear for me.

Comment: Why you need to implement an IAuthorizationFilter ? What is the importance of the authorization event need to fire at 2nd? Are you doing some kind of authorization for the data that return from uow OnActionExecuting?

Comment: `I know that, this is the correct order and I know it's should be that way, But I'm triggering UnitOfWork OnActionExecuting, the reason why I'm using DB when I'm using this filter.`